# extract rows across multiple files using conditions and variables

Tags: bash, awk, genetics

I have a text file of 5,000 rows. Each row corresponds to a unique `FILE` all labelled `gwas*`:

```
CHR     BP          FILE
chr1    12345678    gwas1
chr2    87654321    gwas2
...
```

I have 5,000 `gwas*` files all with unique file names (as found in column 4 above - `FILE`), for example, `gwas1` looks like this:

```
CHR     BP                  
chr1    12345678    
chr1    12345679        
chr1    12356777    
...
```

I want to extract all rows from each `gwas*` file where the `BP` value is within 500,000 (up and down) of the `BP` value in the text file. The `CHR` value must also match. For example:

1. `gwas1` in the text file has the `CHR` value `chr1` and the `BP` value `12,345,678`.
2. I want to extract all rows from `gwas1` which have a `chr1` value in the `CHR` column and which have a `BP` value between `11,845,678` (this value is 500,000 down from the `BP` value in the text file) and `12,845,678` (this value is 500,000 down from the `BP` value in the text file).

I can do this manually for a single gwas file using the below code (this does not use the text file of 5,000 rows however):

```
export CHR="chr11"
export BP=107459522
export WINDOW=500000

awk -v CHR=$CHR -v BP_pos=$(($BP + $WINDOW)) -v BP_neg=$(($BP - $WINDOW)) 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}FNR==1 || ($1 == CHR && $2 < BP_pos && $2 > BP_neg )' gwas1 > gwas1_extract
```

I want to be able to do this for all 5,000 gwas files listed in my text file. The output for every gwas file should only include the rows in which (i) the column `CHR` contained the value for that file (e.g., for `gwas1` this is `chr1`) and the `BP` column contained values that were within 500,000 of the value given in the text file for the `BP` column (for `gwas1` this is 500,000 either side of  `12,345,678`). The output file would look like this:

```
CHR     BP           
chr1    12345678  
chr1    12345679  
chr1    12356777
```

`awk --version` = GNU Awk 4.0.2

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your loop would set `file` successively to each word in _filelist_.  It would take on the values `chr1` in the first iteration, `12345678` in the next one. You need to read one line in each iteration. Google for _bash loop through file line by line_.

Comment: please update the question to include the expected output

Comment: where/how does `SNP=rs1234` come into play? you've referenced this field/value in the description but there's no reference in the code; does the code also need to match on `SNP`? in the main text file can a `FILE` entry (eg, `gwas1`) show up more than once?

Comment: what version of `awk` are you using? what's the output from `awk --version`?

Comment: I'vee updated the question in response to the above comments by @markp-fuso.

Comment: you've removed `SNP` from the inputs but included it in the output ... ? do all files (input and output) have the header row? if no matches are found should the resulting `*_extract` file be created and left empty (or only include the header row)?

Comment: @markp-fuso inclusion of `SNP` in the output was a mistake. Yes, all files have a header row. There will always be a match between the row in the text file and the corresponding `gwas*` file.

Comment: Are you sure the column name `FILE` is `$4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample inputs:

```
$ cat file.txt
CHR     BP      FILE
chr1    12345678        gwas1
chr2    87654321        gwas2
chr4    99999999        gwas4             # file gwas4 does not exist

$ cat gwas1
CHR     BP
chr1    12345678                          # match
chr1    12345679                          # match
chr1    12356777                          # match
chr1    99999999

$ cat gwas2
CHR     BP
chr1    12345678
chr2    87650000                          # match

$ cat gwas3                               # no matches since gwas3 not in file.txt
CHR     BP
chr3    2134234
```

**NOTE:** comments do not exist in actual files

A single `GNU awk` script to process all `gwas*` files:

```
awk -v diff=500000 '

function abs(x) { return (x < 0.0) ? -x : x }

BEGIN         { FS=OFS="\t" }

FNR==NR       { if (FNR>1)                      # 1st file; skip header and ...
                   bp_list[$3][$1]=$2           # save contents in our bp_list[FILE][CHR] array
                next
              }

FNR==1        { close(outfile)                  # close previous output file
                fn=FILENAME
                outfile=fn "_extract"
                if (fn in bp_list)              # if fn in 1st file then ...
                   print > outfile              # print header else ...
                else                            # skip to next input file; also addresses gwas* matching on gwas*_extract files, ie, these will be skipped, too
                   nextfile
                next
              }

fn in bp_list { if ($1 in bp_list[fn] && abs(bp_list[fn][$1] - $2) <= diff)
                   print > outfile
              }
' file.txt gwas*
```

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` for multidimensional arrays (aka array of arrays)

This generates:

```
$ head gwas*extract
==> gwas1_extract <==
CHR     BP
chr1    12345678
chr1    12345679
chr1    12356777

==> gwas2_extract <==
CHR     BP
chr2    87650000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be great!

You might find GNU `AWK`'s [ARGC and ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) useful in your case as

> A program can alter ARGC and the elements of ARGV. Each time awk
> reaches the end of an input file, it uses the next element of ARGV as
> the name of the next input file. By storing a different string there,
> a program can change which files are read. Use "-" to represent the
> standard input. Storing additional elements and incrementing ARGC
> causes additional files to be read.

Thus allowing you to select files to process based on content of file.